# JavaScript optimizer for Windows 8

Tags: javascript, web-development, windows-8, optimization

I'm looking for a JavaScript optimizer and so far, I found two suitables products:

- [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2), whose main objective is to reduce code size
- [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/), which reduces code size and improves overall performance and seems to be the most popular solution nowadays.

While Closure seems to be the perfect solution for me, I'm interested in knowing if there are any alternative to these tools that I missed.

This alternative should, given some JS source:

- reduce the source size
- improve the source performance
- be appliable to big projects

On top of these features, it should

- be runnable on Windows 8
- have at least a test version
- still be maintained (so no YUI compiler)

I have no requirements concerning licensing or price.